# PHP page not rendering properly after conversion to UTF-8

Tags: php, html, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a problem with this page originally encoded in ISO-8859-1, that won't render properly once encoded in UTF-8:

Original ISO-8859-1 page: http://www.maxballet.it/sito/orari.php

UTF-8 page: http://www.maxballet.it/sito/orari2.php

Code:

```
<?PHP
                    switch($orientamento) {
                        case -1:
                            echo '<option value="adulti">Adulti</option>';
                            echo '<option value="bambini_ragazzi">Bambini e ragazzi</option>';
                            echo '<option value="master_formazione">Master e formazione</option>';
                        break;
                        case 'adulti':
                            echo '<option selected value="adulti">Adulti</option>';
                            echo '<option value="bambini_ragazzi">Bambini e ragazzi</option>';
                            echo '<option value="master_formazione">Master e formazione</option>';
                        break;
                        case 'bambini_ragazzi':
                            echo '<option value="adulti">Adulti</option>';
                            echo '<option selected value="bambini_ragazzi">Bambini e ragazzi</option>';
                            echo '<option value="master_formazione">Master e formazione</option>';
                        break;
                        case 'master_formazione':
                            echo '<option value="adulti">Adulti</option>';
                            echo '<option value="bambini_ragazzi">Bambini e ragazzi</option>';
                            echo '<option selected value="master_formazione">Master e formazione</option>';
                        break;
                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <a href="stampa_orari.php?id_disciplina=<?PHP echo $id_disciplina; ?>&orientamento=<?PHP echo $orientamento; ?>" target="_new">Versione stampabile</a>
        </p>
        <?PHP
            switch($orientamento) {
                case -1:
                break;
                case 'adulti':
                    $nome_orientamento='Adulti';
                break;
                case 'bambini_ragazzi':
                    $nome_orientamento='Bambini e ragazzi';
                break;
                case 'master_formazione':
                    $nome_orientamento='Master e formazione';
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
            if($id_disciplina!=-1) {
                if($orientamento!=-1) {
                    $accesso_mysql=mysql_connect($ip_server_mysql, $username_server_mysql, $password_server_mysql);
                    if (!$accesso_mysql) {
                        die('Impossibile accedere a MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    else {
                        $accesso_database=mysql_select_db($nome_database_server_mysql, $accesso_mysql);
                        if (!$accesso_database) {
                            die ('Impossibile accedere al database: ' . mysql_error());
                        }
                        else {
                            $query='SELECT corsi.id AS "corsi.id", corsi.nome AS "corsi.nome", livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso AS "livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso", livelli.nome AS "livelli.nome", lezioni.id AS "lezioni.id", lezioni.giorno AS "lezioni.giorno", lezioni.orario_inizio AS "lezioni.orario_inizio", lezioni.orario_fine AS "lezioni.orario_fine", lezioni.descrizione AS "lezioni.descrizione" FROM (discipline, corsi, livelli_corsi, livelli) LEFT JOIN lezioni ON (livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso=lezioni.id_livello_corso) WHERE discipline.id=corsi.id_disciplina AND corsi.id=livelli_corsi.id_corso AND livelli_corsi.id_livello=livelli.id AND discipline.id=' . $id_disciplina . ' AND corsi.orientamento="' . $nome_orientamento . '" AND livelli_corsi.visualizza_orario=1 ORDER BY FIELD(corsi.orientamento, "Adulti", "Bambini e ragazzi", "Master e formazione"), discipline.nome, corsi.ordine, livelli.ordine, FIELD(lezioni.giorno, "Lunedì", "Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì"), lezioni.orario_inizio, lezioni.orario_fine, lezioni.descrizione;';
                            $risultato_query=mysql_query($query);
                            if(!$risultato_query) {
                                die (mysql_error());
                            }
                            else {
                                $riga=mysql_fetch_array($risultato_query);
                                while($riga!=FALSE) {
                                    $corsi_id_corso=$riga['corsi.id'];
                                    echo '<div class="contenitore_titolo_linea_orario"><div class="contenitore_titolo_orario"><h4 class="titolo_orario">&#9679; ' . $riga['corsi.nome'] . '</h4></div><div class="contenitore_linea_orario"><hr class="linea_orario" /></div></div><div class="orario">';
                                    echo '<table><tr><td class="no_bordo"></td><td class="testo_centrato"><h4>Luned&igrave;</h4></td><td class="testo_centrato"><h4>Marted&igrave;</h4></td><td class="testo_centrato"><h4>Mercoled&igrave;</h4></td><td class="testo_centrato"><h4>Gioved&igrave;</h4></td><td class="testo_centrato"><h4>Venerd&igrave;</h4></td></tr>';
                                    while($riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                        $livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso=$riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso'];
                                        echo '<tr><td class="testo_corsivo">' . $riga['livelli.nome'] . '</td>';
                                        while($riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                            $incremento=1;
                                            echo '<td class="testo_centrato">';
                                            while($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Lunedì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                $orario_inizio_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_inizio'];
                                                $valore_orario_inizio_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_inizio_lezione));
                                                $orario_fine_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_fine'];
                                                $valore_orario_fine_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_fine_lezione));
                                                echo $valore_orario_inizio_lezione . '-' . $valore_orario_fine_lezione; 
                                                if($riga['lezioni.descrizione']!=NULL) {
                                                    echo '<br />' . $riga['lezioni.descrizione'];
                                                }
                                                echo '<br />';
                                                $incremento=0;
                                                $riga=mysql_fetch_array($risultato_query);
                                                if($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Lunedì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                    echo '-<br />';
                                                }
                                            }
                                            echo '</td><td class="testo_centrato">';
                                            while($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Martedì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                $orario_inizio_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_inizio'];
                                                $valore_orario_inizio_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_inizio_lezione));
                                                $orario_fine_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_fine'];
                                                $valore_orario_fine_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_fine_lezione));
                                                echo $valore_orario_inizio_lezione . '-' . $valore_orario_fine_lezione; 
                                                if($riga['lezioni.descrizione']!=NULL) {
                                                    echo '<br />' . $riga['lezioni.descrizione'];
                                                }
                                                echo '<br />';
                                                $incremento=0;
                                                $riga=mysql_fetch_array($risultato_query);
                                                if($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Martedì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                    echo '-<br />';
                                                }
                                            }
                                            echo '</td><td class="testo_centrato">';
                                            while($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Mercoledì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                $orario_inizio_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_inizio'];
                                                $valore_orario_inizio_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_inizio_lezione));
                                                $orario_fine_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_fine'];
                                                $valore_orario_fine_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_fine_lezione));
                                                echo $valore_orario_inizio_lezione . '-' . $valore_orario_fine_lezione; 
                                                if($riga['lezioni.descrizione']!=NULL) {
                                                    echo '<br />' . $riga['lezioni.descrizione'];
                                                }
                                                echo '<br />';
                                                $incremento=0;
                                                $riga=mysql_fetch_array($risultato_query);
                                                if($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Mercoledì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                    echo '-<br />';
                                                }
                                            }
                                            echo '</td><td class="testo_centrato">';
                                            while($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Giovedì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                $orario_inizio_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_inizio'];
                                                $valore_orario_inizio_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_inizio_lezione));
                                                $orario_fine_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_fine'];
                                                $valore_orario_fine_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_fine_lezione));
                                                echo $valore_orario_inizio_lezione . '-' . $valore_orario_fine_lezione;  
                                                if($riga['lezioni.descrizione']!=NULL) {
                                                    echo '<br />' . $riga['lezioni.descrizione'];
                                                }
                                                echo '<br />';
                                                $incremento=0;
                                                $riga=mysql_fetch_array($risultato_query);
                                                if($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Giovedì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                    echo '-<br />';
                                                }
                                            }
                                            echo '</td><td class="testo_centrato">';
                                            while($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Venerdì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                $orario_inizio_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_inizio'];
                                                $valore_orario_inizio_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_inizio_lezione));
                                                $orario_fine_lezione=$riga['lezioni.orario_fine'];
                                                $valore_orario_fine_lezione=date('H:i', strtotime($orario_fine_lezione));
                                                echo $valore_orario_inizio_lezione . '-' . $valore_orario_fine_lezione; 
                                                if($riga['lezioni.descrizione']!=NULL) {
                                                    echo '<br />' . $riga['lezioni.descrizione'];
                                                }
                                                echo '<br />';
                                                $incremento=0;
                                                $riga=mysql_fetch_array($risultato_query);
                                                if($riga['lezioni.giorno']=='Venerdì' && $riga['livelli_corsi.id_livello_corso']==$livelli_corsi_id_livello_corso && $riga['corsi.id']==$corsi_id_corso) {
                                                    echo '-<br />';
                                                }
                                            }
                                            echo '</td>';
                                            if($incremento==1) {
                                                $riga=mysql_fetch_array($risultato_query);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        echo '</tr>';
                                    }
                                    echo '</table></div>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        mysql_close($accesso_mysql);
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
```

This is just the relevant snippet, because the other parts of the code are either shared with other UTF-8 encoded pages which works fine or which handle the different combinations of the values in the checkboxes.

I even tried parsing the file afterwards for BOM and UTF-8 characters with no luck.

Any help on this would be really appreciated, thanks to all in advance.

**UPDATE 1:** Fixing meta tags on the page and converting the whole database from latin1 to utf-8 didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You've got a database in there. did you confirm that your ENTIRE rendering pipeline has been set to utf? client->server->php->db connection->db->table->php->client?

Comment: I red your answer and checked my database, which was actually encoded in latin1. Being utf-8 a superset of latin1 i thought this shouldn't have been an issue, since as long as no utf-8-only character is being inserted into the database the "output" pipeline should work fine anyway. But since i might have been wrong i just went ahead and converted the whole database to utf-8, setting the collation to utf8_unicode_ci and converting both tables and fields using the alter table - convert to command. But the issue is still present. Not sure if this actually converted field's content tough.

Comment: i checked further on what i did and it looks like i did it right. I can confirm that database collation, table encoding, fields encoding and actual fields content is now utf-8.

Comment: don't forget the db connection. every single stage of the entire process has to agree on the charset, or you're going to get corruption.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. have been busy and couldn't try this yet. i guess you mean to use mysql_set_charset? i'll try this and post again.

Comment: that was actually the issue. thank you so much for your help, and if you want to post this as the answer of course i'll mark that as the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your "UTF-8 page" is saying that the content charset is ISO-8859-1:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Change it to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Thanks, i missed that. Unfortunately that didn't work either.